Balancing PhD Research with Interest in a side project and Postdoc Goals
I am currently a first-year PhD student in physics at a U.S. university. My research is focused on a topic I’ve been involved with since my undergraduate studies. I chose this field because of my prior experience and the potential I see for its applications in various areas.
At the same time, I am deeply interested in another area of physics, specifically string theory, which demands a strong foundation in mathematical concepts like differential geometry and group/representation theory—areas where I currently need to improve. My university offers the option to pursue a double major during my PhD, and I am considering adding mathematics as a second major to develop these skills and pursue string theory as a 'side academic interest,' possibly leading to a postdoc in this field.
Given that there are no faculty members at my university specializing in string theory, should I seek out academic collaborations with researchers from other institutions to build a relevant body of work in this area? Or would it be more beneficial to concentrate on my current research project to demonstrate my academic capabilities in my primary field?

What is the other topic you're focused on?

@Anyon I'm currently working on quantum information and computing

So you are a first year student, so have been in the program less than a month now (early September). My take is that you have absolutely no idea how much work it will take to actually come up to speed on, and then start performing research in your advisor's area. Time and effort spent elsewhere is going to be really hard to find without burning yourself out completely (which many people do anyway in pursuit of just one area).

@Jon Custer Thanks so much for the advise! Really appreciate it :)

You might want to check out this question https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/188985/109799. I am referencing that question because I have converged to thinking that the Ph.D. topic must be the primary one and other interests must be pursued as hobbies in free time. I call it to be realistic. I agree with Jon Custer. Still, my case is somewhat different than yours because I like my Ph.D. topic and my other interests equally. But I agree, approaches can be different. Can you update this post when you advance in your career to see which way you chose and how it worked out for you, please?

@Ivan Nepomnyashchikh Will do! Thanks for the comment :)

My question to you is whether this side project would "balance" or "unbalance" your doctoral studies. This is especially true if you need to rely on outside help to work on it.
While taking one or two extra math courses (mathematician writing) should be fine, especially if they support your mainline project, the more important short term efforts should be in your dissertation research.
However, think about the career you want and how to best move past student status into the early career.
Everyone is different of course. Mathematicians are often internally driven to study math. It isn't an option. But it can have an effect on your career, either positive or negative. But that depends on what you want your career to be.
Unlike some "hot" topics today, I doubt (without evidence) that string theory is going to go away in the next few years if you concentrate elsewhere for now. Alternatively you could consider a big change and move to a place that strongly supports that area. Your life. Your choice.

Sure, the OP can take a math "minor" in their PhD, and hopefully put that to good use on their quantum information project. Actually then coming up to speed on string theory is way out of scope for their PhD, and will only harm their progress as well as their relationship with their advisor most likely.
